# dxl CreateProcess failed for system cmd instruction

Tags: ibm-doors

I want to call run a file called csvplot.vbs ([from this site](http://www.end2endzone.com/csvplot-a-command-line-script-which-uses-microsoft-excel-to-plot-a-graph-from-a-comma-separated-values-csv-file/)) to turn a .csv file I have written using dxl (has 5 columns, each with a heading and then just numerical data) into a graph (stored as .png).

I have run the following instruction directly through cmd with success:

```
@echo off
cscript //nologo C:\Users\Administrator\csvplot.vbs C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\Rational\DOORS\9.6\lib\dxl\addins\Verification\Statistics\statGenTest_Top_Level.csv C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\Rational\DOORS\9.6\lib\dxl\addins\Verification\Statistics\statGenTest_Top_Level.png 800 600 1 3 1 4 1 5
pause
```

This produces the desired .png file.

What I want, however, is to be able to execute this through DOORS, so that whenever the script that generates the raw data is run, it also produces a graph.

What I have is this as my test case:

```
string echostr = "@echo off"
string commands = "cscript //nologo C:\\Users\\Administrator\\csvplot.vbs C:\\PROGRA~1\\IBM\\Rational\\DOORS\\9.6\\lib\\dxl\\addins\\Verification\\Statistics\\statGenTest_Top_Level.csv C:\\PROGRA~1\\IBM\\Rational\\DOORS\\9.6\\lib\\dxl\\addins\\Verification\\Statistics\\statGenTest_Top_Level.png 800 600 1 3 1 4 1 5"

system("cmd /c start @echo off") // doesn't recognise echo command
system("cmd /c start " commands "")
```

I get an error:

> "Windows cannot find '@echo'. Make sure you typed the name correctly,
>   and then try again."

I am at a loss on how to get the script to run though cmd from dxl, and I would appreciate any help.  I've only had one previous foray into system() prompts through dxl, and it was only to open a .pdf.  In the meantime I will keep trying to work this out.  Please let me know if I can provide any further information.

**Edit: Further Information**

- @echo: I removed the @ to see how it operates, it brings up a blank
  cmd window and performs no further action.  In order to even run the things in the points below, I left the @ off.
- I deleted "/c start" from the second system() line: this opens one command line with the usual white text at the top, and a second over the top that is completely blank.
- I changed the first line as follows, and commented out the second:

  system("cmd /c start echo off" "\n" commands "")
- --- this got a similar result to the second dot-point, but only with one cmd window, the black (no text one)
- If I don't include the "\n" marker then I get a cmd window with text of "off" commands (where commands is the defined string above).
- If I only have the system("cmd /c start " commands "") line, and not the echo line, then a cmd window briefly flashes and disappears and no further results demonstrating the success of the script appear.

So my issue is this: I know this script works when run directly through command line, the problem I have is that I cannot now run it through dxl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have developed a solid work-around that does exactly what I need.

The issue was that the input I had dxl writing was not going through command line correctly.

Knowing that the script ran from cmd correctly and, in turn, that the script executed from a batch file correctly, and that I could run the batch file from dxl, my solution was as follows:

1. Define the paths in dxl using the format C:\PROGRA~1\PATHNAME\
2. Using the Stream write() command to write the instructions directly
   to a .bat file
3. Then using the system() command to run the .bat file

I have included some of my code, so that maybe it might help someone attempting to do the same thing.  (I'll gladly take any advice on better programming conventions.)

```
// functions used: genFileName(), assume if a variable is not declared here, it was declared under my globals
// genFileName() returns a string of the file name, replacing any " " with "_" so cmd doesn't cry when I run it

string basename = genFileName()    
string fcsv = basename ".csv"    
string csvPath = "blahblahthefilepath" fcsv


   if(fileExists_(csvPath)) isFile = true

   Stream fOut = append(csvPath)

   // === if file does not exist, create, give column names

   if( !isFile){    
   fOut << "Date and Time,count1,count2,count3,count4" "\n"    
   }
   else ack ("File name exists, append stats to file?" // may not be necessary

// === print to file ===    
fOut << datetime "," ctot "," ctc "," cti "," ctnc "\n"


// ===== Create Batch file to run grapher ===    
string columnsToPlot = "1 3 1 4 1 5" // ==> may develop this to allow user to choose    
string graphDim = "800 600" // ==> px dim, may develop for user choice    
string fbat = basename ".bat"    
string batPath = "blahblahthefilepath"    

   Stream batOut = write(batPath fbat)

   batOut << "@echo off" "\n"    
   batOut << "title Batch file to plot statistics for " fcsv "\n"    
   batOut << "cscript //nologo " batPath "csvplot.vbs " batPath fcsv " " batPath basename ".png " graphDim " " columnsToPlot ""


system("cmd /c start " batPath fbat "")



// some infoBox feedback DB to tell the user that the files were created
```

Good luck to anyone else who is attempting something similar, and I hope this is of use to someone.

Answer (score 0):

Does running the dxl script without the @ in front of the echo command work?

Comment: Hi, I have added several dot points down the bottom detailing tests I have run and the results (generally, they didn't work, but at least it didn't crash DOORS (: )